# Load UITableViewCell Nib in UITableView Nib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nib

I'm trying to load custom UITableViewCell nib in UITableView Nib. However, I'm unable to load the data in the table view. The app crashes with error 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'

This is what I did:
1. use a single ViewController to load two .xib files -- one for a UITableView and one for the UITableCellView.

2. drop a UITableView to TableViewNib.xib file. I set the file's class to ViewController and put an outlet to reference the tableView
3. This is the ViewController Code

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.dataSource = self
   ```
4. Create Custom Table View Cell object into an empty TableCellNib.xib file. I added a Custom Class and an identifier like TableCellId

   ```
   class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

   }
   ```
5. ```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {
        print("I am here!")

        let ingredient = self.ingredients[indexPath.row]
           ViewController.register(UINib(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableCellId")

   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCellID", for: indexPath) as? 
    TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


         return cell

       }
   ```

Comment: You need to register your nib also in the viewDidLoad

Comment: @MidhunMP I didn't get what do you mean. what to do exactly?

Comment: I have did the following in viewDidLoad but still the app is crashing same error` ViewController.register(UINib(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableCellId")`

Comment: Did you add that code  before setting the delegate and datasource?

Comment: @MidhunMP yes but still the same result

Comment: In your viewDidLoad write `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableCellId")`